# IDEA install script

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not sure if that is the right place to ask. Please share the better ones if you know it.

We have some specific settings for IntelliJ IDEA in our team and we would like to create something like install script for newcomers. It has to be with a dynamic URL for IDEA and plugins... Is there something which can help us? Or we need to create this script?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for settings, I use a read-only settings repository: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html

This will also sync the list of enabled/disabled plugins. But IMO unless you are very strict about what plugins you use or have an extremely large number of custom settings, IMO it's not too much to ask of a new employee to set up their IDE by hand. Shouldn't take more than 30-60 minutes and it will help them get an overview of what plugins and inspections you are using and why.

Comment: You are right, that it is not too much to ask to set up IDE. I agree with this statement. But I lost in discussion with my manager, so I will need to do it.

Comment: In that case, a settings repository is a good bet, though someone will have to maintain it.